# C# {"ORA-00917: missing comma"} INSERT QUERY ERROR

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to insert these values:

```
int limit = 50000;

int acc_id = 1;

string query = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_ACCOUNT(C-ACCOUNT_NO,DAILY_LIMIT) 
                VALUES ('"+acc_id+"','"+limit+"')";


OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, con);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But getting a missing comma exception:

> C# {"ORA-00917: missing comma"}

Comment: I think you have to add semicolon

Comment: What are the type of your columns?

Comment: did not work @GrantWinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `CURRENT_ACCOUNT` table contains a column with the name `C-ACCOUNT_NO`?  Is the column named `C_ACCOUNT_NO` (with the dash `-` replaced with an underscore `_`) instead?

If the column name genuinely does contain a dash, wrap the column name in double-quotes:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_ACCOUNT(\"C-ACCOUNT_NO\",DAILY_LIMIT) " + // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add semicolon at the end of query..

```
string query = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_ACCOUNT(C-ACCOUNT_NO,DAILY_LIMIT) 
                VALUES ("+acc_id+","+limit+");";
```

Comment: No. This is not _have to_.

Comment: acct id and limit and are of what type in oracle databse? @SaddaHussain

Comment: both are numbers in database @Viru

Comment: then why are using **'** single apostrophe in query..remove that...I will update in answer too @SaddaHussain

Comment: @SaddaHussain you can put your queris here itself.....either me or someone else will help you....but cant do skype